# Which part of the daemon RPC is restricted?

Tags: monerod, rpc

When running `monerod` with `restricted-rpc` which of the rpc methods will not be allowed?

Also, is [the daemon](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) RPC documentation on getmonero.org up to date? If not, is there an up to date version somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When running `monerod` with `restricted-rpc` which of the rpc methods will not be allowed?

From the help:

```
Restrict RPC to view only commands and do not return privacy sensitive data in RPC calls
```

In the context of the daemon, when running with `restricted-rpc`, any potentially private information is restricted. One such example is the `/get_info` command, when in restricted mode, a number of the returned fields are omitted/masked.

> Also, is the daemon RPC documentation on getmonero.org up to date?

It's the most up-to-date documentation available beyond reading the code. It had a major refresh not long ago, but there are already minor changes (things like additional fields that may have been added in responses for example). Whilst it may not be fully up-to-date, what is documented will work as documented because we aim to ensure any changes to the RPC are backwards compatible.

Comment: So there is no way to get a concrete list/description of the restricted set of rpc methods, other than reading the source code? Do you you which are the relevant files to look at?

Comment: If your search for "restricted" in [this file](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/rpc/core_rpc_server.cpp), you can see what's omitted.

Comment: And if you search in the [header](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/rpc/core_rpc_server.h), you can see which are not even registered in restricted mode.

Answer (score 4):

> When running monerod with restricted-rpc which of the rpc methods will
>   not be allowed?

The following changes occur when Monerod daemon runs in Restricted Mode via `restricted-rpc` and/or `rpc-restricted-bind-port` options.

The following RPC methods are not registered:

```
flush_txpool
generateblocks
get_alternate_chains
get_bans
get_coinbase_tx_sum
get_peer_list
in_peers
mining_status
on_get_connections
on_set_bans
out_peers
relay_tx
save_bc
set_bans
set_limit
set_log_categories
set_log_hash_rate
set_log_level
start_mining
start_save_graph
stop_daemon
stop_mining
stop_save_graph
sync_info
update
```

> Also, is the daemon RPC documentation on getmonero.org up to date? If
>   not, is there an up to date version somewhere?

You can find interesting alternative reference at [Monerod Restricted RPC Mode](https://github.com/Mitchellpkt/monero_archival_project/wiki/Monerod-Restricted-RPC-Mode) and referenced code at [monero-project/monero/rpc](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/tree/master/src/rpc).

Comment: "I did not find a complete daemon RPC documentation on getmonero.org" <- You never looked at [this](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) then.

Comment: And the reference doc you used ("Monerod Restricted RPC Mode") is hideously out of date.

Comment: The question itself links to the documentation.