# How do `rpc-bind-ip` and `restricted-rpc` and `rpc-login` interact?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

Let's say that I were to pass `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0` to `monerod`, and also `--restricted-rpc` (along with the external bind confirmation), what would the outcome be? What does the second command do when interacting with the first? What happens when we add `rpc-login` specifications into the mix?

I'd love to understand how the different combinations of these parameters interact. What's going on under the hood?

- `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0`
- `--restricted-rpc`
- `--rpc-login user:pw`
- `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --restricted-rpc`
- `--restricted-rpc --rpc-login user:pw`
- `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --rpc-login user:pw`
- `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --restricted-rpc --rpc-login user:pw`

Answer (score 1):

`--restricted-rpc`, [answered here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10926/7493) and detailed in the `--help`:

> Restrict RPC to view only commands and do not return privacy sensitive data in RPC calls

You'd probably want to use this if you plan on making your daemon publicly accessible.

`--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0`, means that the daemon will bind (listen) on all the IP addresses on all interfaces.

`--rpc-login user:pw`, means that a username "user" and password "pw" is required to access the RPC interface. You'd probably want to use this if you plan on making your daemon publicly accessible.

All these options are documented in the help output (`monerod --help`), and you can use any mixture/combination of them (or none at all).

Comment: If I put "restricted-rpc=true" in my config file, do I still have to put "rpc-restricted-bind-ip" directive in there? Or does the former automatically turn the "rpc-bind-ip" directive in a "restricted" one?

Comment: "If I put "restricted-rpc=true" in my config file, do I still have to put "rpc-restricted-bind-ip" directive in there?" <- No. "Or does the former automatically turn the "rpc-bind-ip" directive in a "restricted" one?" <- Yes.

Comment: @jtgrassie, do you have the ability to link to where in the code the if/else clauses for the command line arguments are parsed?

Comment: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/94e67bf96bbc010241f29ada6abc89f49a81759c/src/daemon/daemon.cpp#L93-L103 and https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/94e67bf96bbc010241f29ada6abc89f49a81759c/src/daemon/main.cpp#L71-L83